# Joda Time - difference in "complete" months between two dates

Tags: java, jodatime

How to calculate the number of "full" months between two dates with joda time, dropping incomplete months?
For example, I have 2 dates

```
LocalDate from = new LocalDate (2018, 9, 10);
LocalDate to = new LocalDate (2018, 11, 15);
```

Between these dates there is one "full" month - October from 1 to 31. 
So I want to get is the number "1" by dropping the "incomplete" months - September and November

I need something like this

```
System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(from, to).getMonths()); // returns 2
System.out.println(Months.**completed**MonthsBetween(from, to).getMonths()); // returns 1
```

UPD 1.
I could achieve what I want as follows:

```
LocalDate from = new LocalDate (2018, 9, 10);
LocalDate to = new LocalDate (2018, 11, 15);

if (to.getDayOfMonth() != 1)
    from = from.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
if (to.getDayOfMonth() != 1)
    to = to.withDayOfMonth(1);

System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(from, to).getMonths());
```

but maybe there is an out of the box method?

Comment: So you want the start of the next month after `from` to the start of the `to` date.

Comment: I highly recommend you use the JSR 310 library built-in for Java 8 and available for Java 6. You will get much better support for it as well as it largely replaces jodatime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773160/joda-time-difference-in-months-between-two-dates

Comment: I’m not a Joda-Time user, but I’d be surprised if there was an out-of-the box method. There are very many ways to count months, it would be unreasonable to put them all in the library. So I suggest that something like what you are doing is necessary.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did my answer helped u somehow

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this means that you simply want to remove one month from each interval and do a difference between them?

```
    LocalDate fromMinusOne = from.minus(Months.ONE);
    LocalDate toMinusOne = to.minus(Months.ONE);

    System.out.println(Months.monthsBetween(fromMinusOne, toMinusOne).getMonths());
```

Comment: No, I want to drop the first and last month, if it does not start from the first day of the month, and count the remaining number of full months

Answer (score 0):

`Joda Time` provides methods to extract `days`, `months` and `years` between two dates. Create two instances of you date.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.parse("1970-01-01", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
DateTime endDate = DateTime.parse("2015-02-25", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

You can create your date instances in `LocalDate` as well instead of `DateTime`.

Now, complete months between above two dates can be found easily with,

```
int months = Months.monthsBetween(startDate.withDayOfMonth(1), endDate.withDayOfMonth(1)).getMonths()
```

For days,

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()
```

Difference between two dates in months

For years,

```
int years = Years.yearsBetween(startDate, endDate).getYears();
```